# Styling jQuery widget divs

Tags: jquery, css

When I try to modify the class `#dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar` there is no visual change.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

```css
#dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

becouse the `.ui-dialog-titlebar` is not in `#dialog`.
you should send int `dialogClass` and use by the class.

javascript:

```
$(function() {
    $("#dialog").dialog({dialogClass: 'test'});
});
```

css:

```
.test .ui-dialog-titlebar {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

or you can change all the `.ui-dialog-titlebar` (but i think you don't want to do this)

Answer (score 0):

Try `.ui-dialog .ui-widget-header` to target the titlebar.  The `.ui-widget-header` class is appended to the header of the dialog box. Check the jQuery documentation for more details: https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog > .ui-widget-header {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog"></div>
```

Comment: Ideally I am just applying a customization to this particular ID (which I can do with other widgets, such as accordion). Is dialog a special case?

Comment: @DanielWilliams The `#dialog` element actually becomes the sibling element of `.ui-dialog-titlebar`, so your CSS would never be able to select it by drilling down to `#dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar`

Comment: What was frustrating is that the method worked perfectly for the accordion widget where I was setting `#accordion .ui-accordion-header` and the style was applied. Just couldn't get it to work the same for dialog.

Comment: I just noticed that to style `.ui-accordion-header` on its own doesn't actually affect the look of the widget. Whereas styling `.ui-dialog-titlebar` on its own was the only way I could get it to work. Unless I'm missing something (I'm new to jQuery) this is pretty inconsistent!

Answer (score 0):

You can addClass for `.ui-dialog-titlebar` when call open dialog.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    open: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).parent().find('.ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('ui-dialog-modified');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog-titlebar.ui-dialog-modified {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="dialog" title="Dialog"></div>
```